# Animate fullcalendar on month change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

**I have a monthly calendar with fullCalendar jQuery plugin. I want to apply transition on month change.**

Any related links or demo would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Available Views](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/)

```
 viewDisplay: function(view) {
    if(view.title == 'month'){

       //Do Stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: viewDisplay has now been deprecated and viewRender use is suggested and I am new to jquery so can you please give any demo having animation whenever month changes.